# deleted a folder from root(user), ubuntu how do i access the trash bin from terminal?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, paths, webmin

i have deleted a folder from the root user dir (same where var,usr,home,etc,lib is stored) using the Webmin browser GUI ...on url http:// IP :10000

**VPS:**

- ubuntu 18.04
- User : root
- no GUI, only SSH and Webmin providing by the hosting site

**i have found lot of answers, use:**

```
cd .local/share/Trash/files
$ cd .local/share/Trash/
~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

**error:**

```
/root/.local/share/Trash: No such file or directory
```

these do not exist anymore...please anyone update the path..

**i m currently at:**

```
root@kivee:~#
```

How can i restore it?

Comment: @user535733 i deleted it with the Webmin browser GUI ...on url http://xxx.xx.IP.xx:10000

Comment: @user535733 yeah sorry, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trash is maintained and used by graphical file managers in your desktop environment only. No trash is implemented when you use the command line, neither as normal user or as administrator. The command `rm` will remove files without moving them to a trash. I will be surprised if your Webmin browser gui works with a trash. It likely does not. So your remove operation effectively removed the files definitively, just as if you would have removed them using the `rm` command over `ssh`.

As you found out, you effectively can find the Trash under the user's `.local/share/Trash`. However, the home folder of the root user, `/root` normally will have no trash because you should not run any graphical file manager directly as root.

Comment: ohhk, i understand it ...thanks for the elaborated explanation, though i requested a backup from my hosting provider and they restored the server.